# How to override tab related adminhtml

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, magento-1.9, overriding

I need to override this block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related.

**config.xml**

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <product_edit_tab_related>Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit_Tab_Related</product_edit_tab_related>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>

    </global>
```

**Related.php**

```
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Product_Edit_Tab_Related extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related
{


    /**
     * Prepare collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {}
}
```

Only need override _prepareCollection function but i can't.

Can you help me?

Comment: please improve your question and specify the problem. why can't you override this block? is there any error or changed code that has no effect? also provide more context like file paths (may be an issue), namespace used and what you actually want to achieve with this override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:- Related.php Should be :-

```
<?php
class Company_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Related
{
   protected function _prepareCollection()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: class name does not matter, it can also be Company_Module_Block_CustomRelated.